# Next Line Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

What in my code is causing the code printed to be on the next line?

```
function GetSelected (selectTag) {
    var selIndexes = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < selectTag.options.length; i++) {
        var optionTag = selectTag.options[i];
        if (optionTag.selected) {
            if (selIndexes.length > 0)
                selIndexes += "";
            selIndexes = optionTag.value;
        }
    }

    var info = document.getElementById ("info");
    if (selIndexes.length > 0) {
        info.innerHTML = selIndexes;
    }
    else {
        info.innerHTML = "There is no selected option";
    }
}
```

Here's one of the option in the combobox:

```
<select option="single"  name= "viocat" id="viocat" onchange="GetSelected (this);" class = "form-control">
    <option>Choose category ...</option>
    <option value="<?php
        $con = mysqli_connect("///") or die (mysql_error());
        $sql = mysqli_query ($con, "SELECT violationcategory, MAX(code) AS highest_id FROM tbl_violation where violationcategory = '\r\n DL'");

        $sql = "SELECT violationcategory, MAX(code) AS highest_id FROM tbl_violation where violationcategory = '\r\n OR'";

        $result = mysql_query ($sql,$con);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $i = $row['highest_id'];
            $i++;
            echo "OR - " .$i;
        }
    ?> "> Driver's License Related</option>
</select>
```

Here's where to be displayed:

```
 <label type= "text" id="info" name="viocode" class = "form-control">
```

Comment: I can't see where this code prints anything. Have you given us the correct code snippet?

Comment: This would be a good time to read [ask] as it is very difficult to understand your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure exactly what you mean by next line but, from part of the question that you deleted, I think it is because you start your PHP block on a new line.
Instead of:

```
<option>Choose category ...</option>
    <option value="
 <?php
```

Try:

```
<option>Choose category ...</option>
    <option value="<?php
```

Comment: Hahaha thanks! Such a great debugger! :) I didn't notice it. Thank you soooo much!